# How to implement Big Integer subtraction in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, subtraction

I want to subtract 2 big integer numbers and by not using the API like BigInteger, and implement the sum operation on my own.

I have already implemented, as shown in the following, where I can add 2 big integer numbers not using `BigInteger`.

```
class BigIntAdd{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "7654729850328997631007285998163550104";
        String s2 = "5980139243970186632651869926335829102";
        add(s1, s2);
    }

    public static String add(String addend1, String addend2) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int i1 = addend1.length() - 1, i2 = addend2.length() - 1, carry = 0;
              i1 >= 0 || i2 >= 0 || carry != 0;
              i1--, i2-- ) {
            int digit1 = i1 < 0 ? 0 :
                         Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend1.charAt(i1)));
            int digit2 = i2 < 0 ? 0 :
                         Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend2.charAt(i2)));

            int digit = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
            if (digit > 9) {
                carry = 1;
                digit -= 10;
            } else {
                carry = 0;
            }

            buf.append(digit);
        }
        return buf.reverse().toString();
    }
```

How can I revise the code so that it can *subtract* 2 big integer numbers?

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `+`'s with `-` and `>9` with `<0`?

Comment: Show us your attempt at implementing subtraction. Think about how you'd do it on paper, and adapt your addition code to mimic the paper process. It's very similar, except carrying will be replaced by borrowing.

Comment: Funny, I saw the exact same question no so long ago... What is the problem ? What is the output expected and the current one ? What is the input constraint (negative allow ?)

Comment: @AxelH It is a pretty common final project for Data Structures in Uni

Comment: @Turtle, 2hours ago (max) with the exact code. (But it was probably deleted, don't find my comment) But I don't remember the OP name... edit: **tobias_k** made good use of is reputation

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to (aka exactly the same as) this [now deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631804/how-to-implement-a-big-integer-addition-operation-in-java) by a different user. Did you "borrow" your classmate's code, or do you have multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of subtraction of BigInteger. Sorry in advance as I used character array instead of `String` to represent the numbers, but you can get the idea.

```
private static char[] subtractValue(char[] greater, char[] smaller) {
        char[] result = new char[greater.length];
        int index = 1;
        int carry = 0;
        int digit;

        // 1. subtract shorter part
        while (index <= smaller.length) {
                digit = Character.getNumericValue(greater[greater.length-index]) - Character.getNumericValue(smaller[smaller.length-index]) - carry;
                carry = digit < 0 ? 1 : 0;
                digit = digit + (carry == 1? 10 : 0);
                result[greater.length - index] = Character.forDigit(digit, 10);
                index++;
        }

        // 2. carry rippling
        while (index <= greater.length) {
                digit = Character.getNumericValue(greater[greater.length-index]) - carry;
                carry = digit < 0 ? 1 : 0;
                digit = digit + (carry == 1 ? 10 : 0);
                result[greater.length - index] = Character.forDigit(digit, 10);
                index++;
        }

        // 3. trim out trailing zeros
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < result.length - 1 && result[i] == '0'; i++) {
        }
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(result, i, result.length);
}
```

You can invoke it this way:

```
char[] bigger = new char[]{'7', '7', '8'};
char[] smaller = new char[]{'1', '2', '3'};
String result = Arrays.toString(subtractValue(bigger, smaller));
System.out.println(result);
```

Hope it helps!

### Edit

#### 1. Subtract shorter part

This section of code simply subtract every `i`th digit of `smaller` from `greater` and if there is any carry, it will propagate the carry for `(i + 1)`th digit.

```
 2 1 0
 1 2 3
 -----
 0 8 7
```

#### 2. Carry rippling

This section subtract if there is any carry left from prevous step and propagate the new carry if needed until the carry becomes zero.

```
In (1) part, we did - 
2 0 0
0 7 8
------
0 2 2

Now, we have still carry 1 left from (1) to subtract

2 0 0
1
-----
1 2 2
```

#### 3. Trim out trailing zeros

This section trim out the trailing zeros.

```
1 2 3
1 2 1
-----
0 0 2

After trimming zeros

2
```

Comment: No worries but before I accept the answer and upvote, could you go into details very briefly with comments on what each line is doing? Tried to understand it but having trouble. And what would be the time complexity for it?

Comment: Thought I did. Thank you Kaidul!